# How do I configure NServiceBus to scan an assembly for IMessage?

Tags: c#, nservicebus, messaging

I am working with code that I have not written and am trying to understand why a particular piece of functionality is not working the way I intend. In particular, I have three projects within my solution:

```
API
Messages
    Events
Processors
```

Events is a folder within Messages. API will communicate with Processors using NServiceBus via messages defined in `Messages/Events`. Each of the classes in `Messages/Events` extends `IMessage`.

Now within a configuration file for the bus that is shared by both Processors and API, I found these lines:

```
var conventionsBuilder = config.Conventions();
conventionsBuilder.DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("DE.STEP.Messages") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"));
return config;
```

This was implemented earlier, and the classes inside `Messages/Events` did NOT extend `IMessage` at an earlier time, instead the above code defined where and what a message could be qualified as. Now, since I have introduced `IMessage`, I figured I could remove those 3 lines of code. However, when I do, no messages ever make it to my queue from API. The code that attempts this publish is `Bus.Publish<>();`

How should I configure this so that I do not need to have a hard-coded string referencing the assembly where the messages are? I want my code to scan the solution for anything that extends `IMessage` and treat it as something that can be published and can be handled.

EDIT: As per the NServiceBus docs

```
By default, NServiceBus scans all assemblies in the endpoint 
bin folder to find types implementing its interfaces so that 
it can configure them automatically.
```

And `Messages.dll` appears in the `bin` of both API and Processors. So since `Messages.dll` contains all of my `IMessages`, shouldn't the default behavior suffice to make them available for publishing / subscribing? I.e. shouldn't removing the 3 lines in question have no effect?

Comment: Have you tried 1) Implementing `IEvent` instead of `IMessage` and 2) Are your message endpoint mappings set up correctly?

Comment: Message end point mappings are indeed correct, as I said with those 3 lines that specifically designate where to look for messages, the entire pipeline works. I can try the `IEvent` thing, though I don't understand why that would work over `IMessage`, since the latter is just a broader definition than the former

Comment: If changing to IEvent doesn't work, can you share your mappings for a single event? Looking at the routing rules for events vs messages, it seems like you can only have a single route set up per message, as the code doesn't know whether it's a command or event. So in the case of messages, it clears all routes for the message and only keeps track of the last one in the file for that type.

Comment: That worked! If you'd like to post an answer I'll approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hierarchy of an event, if you're not using unobtrusive configuration, should be as follows:

```
ConcreteEvent : IEvent : IMessage
```

The reason for this is, after having had a look at the source code, your message endpoint mappings are processed as follows:

```
foreach (var mapping in messageEndpointMappings)
{
    mapping.Configure((messageType, address) =>
    {
        var conventions = context.Settings.Get<Conventions>();
        if (!(conventions.IsMessageType(messageType) || conventions.IsEventType(messageType) || conventions.IsCommandType(messageType)))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (conventions.IsEventType(messageType))
        {
            router.RegisterEventRoute(messageType, address);
            return;
        }

        router.RegisterMessageRoute(messageType, address);
    });
}
```

`Conventions.IsEventType` is a lookup implemented as follows:

```
EventsConventionCache.ApplyConvention(t, type => IsEventTypeAction(type));
```

I won't give you the full call stack but basically, you end up here:

```
t => typeof(IEvent).IsAssignableFrom(t) && typeof(IEvent) != t
```

This will evaluate as `false` for a concrete event only implementing `IMessage`, so `RegisterEventRoute` is never called for your event but rather it'll be treated as an `IMessage`, which follows different routing rules (only one route per `IMessage`).

Answer (score 0):

In short, you must have IEvent interface on your event class to be able to use IBus.Publish if you are not using unobtrusive configuration.